# I wants to scrape indiamart.com but it returns none

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new at scrapy. I want to scrap data from alibaba.com but I'm getting none. I don't know where is the problem. Here is my code

```
class IndiaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'india'
allowed_domains = ['indiamart.com']
# search_value = 'car'
start_urls = [f'https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=laptop&prdsrc=1&res=RC4']

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
def request_header(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls, callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent':self.user_agent})

def parse(self, response):
    title = response.xpath("//span[@class='elps elps2 p10b0 fs14 tac mListNme']/a/text()").get()
    related_link = response.xpath("//span[@class='elps elps2 p10b0 fs14 tac mListNme']/a/@href").get()
        
    yield{
        'titling':title,
        'rel_link':related_link
    }
```

And I am getting

```
2023-02-14 15:20:34 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=car&prdsrc=1&res=RC4>
```

{'titling': None, 'rel_link': None, 'images': []}
2023-02-14 15:20:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

I was getting results yesterday, and it is working good but today it returns none. it is not javascript based website. I tried more than one time but returns same

Comment: you are trying to access item's title?

Comment: Acctually I want to scrap product_name , product_title , product_price and product_detail link. This is code is just for sample but I getting eror

Comment: @Sarfraz your last 3 questions have the same problem. The data is populated with JavaScript. You can check this by disabling JavaScript in your browser and refresh the page so you can see the differences.

Comment: Yeah...! Its my fault. I don't have idea how to disable javascript. Now I am learning with tutorial. thanks for answering me.

Comment: @SuperUser can you please help me now I am doing with playwright method and now I am getting {referor:none}, Means I am gettting nothing. how I can solve this can you please help me on it...?

Comment: @Sarfraz I have no experience with playwright.

Comment: Okay then I am going to posting a new question. thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SuperUser told you, the spider gets `None` because the site uses Javascript to render the product information. If you disable Javascript in your browser and reload the page, you will see that the products are not displayed.

However you can get the information from one of the `<script>` tags.

```py
import scrapy
import json


class AlibabaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "alibaba"
    allowed_domains = ["alibaba.com"]
    search_value = "laptop"
    start_urls = [f"https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&tab=all&SearchText={search_value}"]

    def parse(self, response):
        raw_data = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.__page__data__config')]/text()").extract_first()
        raw_data = raw_data.replace("window.__page__data__config = ", "").replace("window.__page__data = window.__page__data__config.props", "")
        data = json.loads(raw_data)

        title = data["props"]["offerResultData"]["offerList"][0]["information"]["puretitle"]
        yield {"title": title} # Laptops Laptop Cheapest OEM Core I5...
```

Comment: I tried this and this is working well thanks. But I'm new to scrapy can you tell  how `window.__page__data__config` works, and is this applicable for all other websites that is javascript populated